# Modifying Field Level Security throws an error

Tags: schema, fls

When trying to change the Field Level Security of a specific field, I am getting the following error:

> Error - Unable to Access Page
> You are missing information needed by the page you have attempted to access. If you believe this is an error, please refresh your screen. If the error persists, please report it to our Customer Support team and provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

What could be the reasons I am getting this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[To modify Field Level Security](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_fields_fls.htm&type=5), you need the following permissions on your user Profile/Permission Set:

1. Manage Profiles and Permission Sets
2. Customize Application

Your user might have [View Setup and Configuration permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386319&type=1), which is why he/she is allowed to open the Object Manager, but they might be missing the above permissions.

View Setup and Configuration:

> Allows the user to view the App Setup menu and Administrative Settings pages.